# How to use Contact Form 7 shortcode value in a page?

Tags: php, shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

I’m a WordPress enthusiast. I am trying to accomplish something but I haven’t found a way to.

Here’s the deal, I’m trying to use the submitted values of a form I created on contact form 7 in a script I added into the same WordPress page where the form is.

I have a script that I want to insert these values into, but when I type in the CF7 shortcode like [your-name] it comes as plain text.

How do I pass these values into shortcode I can use outside of contact form 7?

Comment: Check This Wordpress support topic https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-shortcode-attributes-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: in which place you are using the shortcode inside the form or in the script code or using it on the page ? is your shortcode will be the contact form shortcode?plz clear it

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan18 I want to use the CF7 shortcode on the page body where I’m running a script so basically I want to use it to replace some values of the script. When a user submits the form this script runs so I want it to have the values of the form submitted